# Top 3 sub categories in each category

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

[image]

I got this report done with Tableau but I want to try to do the same thing with Python-Pandas.

Basically, I want to find the top 3 sub-categories by total sales of each Category

```
total_sales = df.groupby(['Category','Sub-Category']).agg(total_sales=('Sales','sum')).sort_values(['Category','total_sales'],ascending = (True,False))
```

Here is my code. It gets the total sales of each sub category but I don't know how to limit by top 3.

Here is the database structure
[image]

Thanks for your input

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: the database is call Super Store from Tableau. Here is the link https://community.tableau.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/1236-102-2-15278/Sample%20-%20Superstore.xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the solution proposed by @WGP could be simplified in this way:

```
data.groupby(['category', 'sub-category'])['price'].agg('sum').groupby(level=0).nlargest(3)
```

the [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) function does the descending ordering operation by default.

P.S.
I don't know how your data are structured but I think that prior to aggregating and summing, if the dollar sign is in the price column, you need to strip it and then cast the column to float.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use another groupby and then use the nlargest function. 
The code below should hopefully give you the answer you want

```
total_sales = (
   df
   .groupby(['Category', 'Sub-Category'], as_index=False)
   .agg(total_sales=('Sales', 'sum'))
   .groupby(['Category'])['total_sales']
   .nlargest(3)
   .sort_values(['Category', 'total_sales'], ascending=(True, False))
)
```

Comment: your code doesn't work but from your code, I change my code and now it works. Here is my code
total_sales = (df.groupby(['Category', 'Sub-Category'])
               .agg(total_sales=('Sales', 'sum'))
               .sort_values(['Category','total_sales'],ascending = (True,False))
               .groupby(['Category'])['total_sales']
               .nlargest(3))

so, I change as_index = True
and I sort_values before I do the second group_by

Comment: Oh yeah, only needed to groupby the one variable in the second groupby, have amended the code now.

Answer (score 0):

I change the code from WGP a bit and now it works.

```
total_sales = (df.groupby(['Category', 'Sub-Category'])
           .agg(total_sales=('Sales', 'sum'))
           .groupby(['Category'])['total_sales']
           .nlargest(3))
```